# Explanation of python reference behavior when creating list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, reference

When creating a new nested list the following way:

```
test_list = [[""]]*5
```

unexpected behavior happens, appending to an index the following modifications happens:

```
test_list[1].append(2)
[['', 2], ['', 2], ['', 2], ['', 2], ['', 2]]
```

when doing the following it works as I would expect:

```
test_list[1] = test_list[1] + [0]
[[''], ['', 0], [''], [''], ['']]
```

but when using the += operator the same odd thing happens

```
test_list[1] += [0]
[['', 0], ['', 0], ['', 0], ['', 0], ['', 0]]
```

when the list is defined as following: `[[""] for i in range(len(5))]` all the examples return the expected output.

What is going on? Is it some reference thing I am not understanding?

Comment: That's what I don't like most in languages like Java, Python, etc - They're using references implicitly. Of course, once you know that, you can handle it. But C++ makes it obvious - which I first didn't like, but now really appreciate.

Comment: Be careful of this *gotcha* too: [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list that has five elements which point to the same list.

When you call `test_list[1].append(2)`, it appends number 2 to the list, which appends it to all lists.

When you call `test_list[1] = test_list[1] + [0]`, a new instance of a list is created, and is assigned to `test_list[1]`. Now in index 1 you have a different list than all other 4.

Here, `test_list[1] += [0]`, `+=` is translated to `test_list[1].append(0)`, which appends zero to all of the lists.

An example to understand `test_list[1] = test_list[1] + [0]`:

```
lst = [0]
print(lst) 
# output: [0]

lst += [1]
print(lst) 
# output: [0, 1]

lst.append(2)
print(lst) 
# output: [0, 1, 2]

lst2 = lst + [3]
print(lst) 
# output: [0, 1, 2]
# the lst did not change!

print(lst2) 
# output: [0, 1, 2, 3]
# a new instance of a list which is not lst
```

Now, let's see the object ids of the elements:

```
test_list = [[""]]*5
print(test_list)
# output: [[''], [''], [''], [''], ['']]

for i in range(5):
    object_id = id(test_list[i])
    print(object_id)
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168

test_list[1] = test_list[1] + [0]
print(test_list)
# output: [[''], ['', 0], [''], [''], ['']]

for i in range(5):
    object_id = id(test_list[i])
    print(object_id)
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4417503368     !!!!
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168
# output: 4405988168
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `test_list = [[""]] * 5` you are creating 5 references to the same list. This means there is **ONLY ONE ROW** in the memory.

When you modify a row, if affects the row in memory, and since all other "rows" refer to it, they will simply use the list in memory which is up-to-date.

**This however creats a list of 5 lists in memory:**

```
test_list = [[""] for i in range(len(5))]
```

---

You could find an [example and explanation in wtfpython](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-a-tic-tac-toe-where-x-wins-in-the-first-attempt):

```
# Let's initialize a row
row = [""]*3 #row i['', '', '']
# Let's make a board
board = [row]*3
```

Output:

```
>>> board
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
>>> board[0]
['', '', '']
>>> board[0][0]
''
>>> board[0][0] = "X"
>>> board
[['X', '', ''], ['X', '', ''], ['X', '', '']]
```

**Explanation:**

When we initialize `row` variable, this visualization explains what happens in the memory.

[image]

And when the `board` is initialized by multiplying the `row`, this is what happens inside the memory (each of the elements `board[0]`, `board[1]` and `board[2]` is a reference to the same list referred by `row`)

[image]

We can avoid this scenario here by not using `row` variable to generate `board`. (Asked in [this](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/issues/68) issue).

```
>>> board = [['']*3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> board[0][0] = "X"
>>> board
[['X', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```